# how to know the FTP username and password

Tags: amazon-web-services, wordpress

i created wordpress website using cloudFormation and when i try to update my plugins, it asks for **host name**, **FTP username** and **FTP password**.
How do i get these?

I think i have to log into the server, but i don't know what to look for there and how

Also, was it the right choice to use cloudformation to create a wordpress blog?

Answer (score 1):

WordPress doesn't need FTP for updating itself or the plugins. The FTP crendentials are only prompted if the WordPress fails to write to these directories – typically due to incorrect file permissions. The user running the WordPress PHP scripts needs to have write access to these folders.

It's completely ok to use AWS CloudFormation for running WordPress. As a matter of fact running WordPress basic single instance is one of the CloudFormation [Sample Solutions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/sample-templates-applications-us-west-1.html).

However, if you aren't familiar with maintaining servers, it might be better to use WordPress as a service. While WordPress.org is for the open source software, WordPress.com [offers](https://wordpress.com/pricing/) maintained blog environment.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but i am stuck now. How can i update the plugins?